# Drag and Drop image with iOS 13 modalPresentationStyleAutomatic

Tags: swift, iphone, drag-and-drop, ios13, uimodalpresentationstyle

I've a problem to drag and drop images with the new presentation style automatic.

The images are subclass of UIImageView
overriding func touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded. I've also tried to put `self.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` inside touch began to disable the touch of the view.

[image]

If I set `segue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` it works, but I would like to have the same behavior also with the Automatic style.

Normal behavior:

[image]

any idea?

Comment: It's a conflict. Even if you disable the ability to dismiss the "not quite fullscreen" modal, it's still a poor user experience trying to drag while the screen moves down. Making fullscreen is the only option I know of. Or you change the UI so the dragging is horizontal.

Comment: @rmaddy mention to disable the ability would be to set `isModalInPresentation` to `true`. However, I would agree for this to not be the best workaround.

Comment: What happens if you set a delegate and implement `presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_:)` to return `false`?

Comment: Also what you are doing is not true drag and drop... You might try that.

Comment: @matt presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_:) didn't work...